# CreateFileW with exclusive access succeeds when LoadLibraryEx called with LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE

Tags: c++, winapi

I was under the assumption that if you use CreateFileW requesting exclusive access, that if it was already opened I should receive a sharing violation. However, I've come across an example where this is not the case. If LoadLibraryEx is called to load a DLL with the LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE flag set, then CreateFileW returns successfully. However there are operations that will be rejected (such as setting attributes like end of file). Is there a better way to detect if these files are open? Am I using CreateFileW incorrectly? Loading a DLL without the LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE flag does result in CreateFileW failing indicating it can not access the file because it is in use by another process.

```
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibraryEx(L"\\Pathto\\module.dll", NULL, NULL);
DWORD access = GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE | WRITE_OWNER | WRITE_DAC | ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY;
DWORD creation = OPEN_EXISTING;
DWORD flags = FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT;
HANDLE file = CreateFileW(L"\\Pathto\\module.dll", access, 0, NULL, creation, flags, 0);
```

The above will result in CreateFileW failing with error code 32 (can't access cause it is in use by another process) which is the expected result. If I add the flag to LoadLibraryEx:

```
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibraryEx(name, NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
```

And use the exact same call to CreateFileW then I'm told it's successful, although I will run into problems later when attempting to set end of file (as an example). Additionally, deleting the file will fail with an access denied error (without the application or any other having an open handle).

Other odd behavior involves hard links with loaded libraries. If I generate a new hard link to the loaded module, and try to delete the alternate newly created hard link, it also fails (NO open file handles, just loaded module). Why? Shouldn't it just remove the link and dereference the link count, or schedule deletion on module close since I could have obtained exclusive access previously?

Also of note, the process itself runs in a privileged user account with the following additional privileges enabled:
SE_SECURITY_NAME, SE_BACKUP_NAME, SE_RESTORE_NAME, SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME

How would one determine if you truly have exclusive access to a file when libraries are loaded?

Edit: Just to doubly check, I verified no other open handles besides loading the module via the SysInternals tool "handle".

Comment: I'm guessing the data is simply placed in memory but the file isn't kept open. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141120-00/?p=43573 may be relevant.

Comment: I think there is more to it than this. It is clearly still being referenced by the owning process (listed as a DLL for the life of the process if you look in SysInternals Process Explorer). Your link also states that it is mapped into the process address space.

Also, why the downvotes with no explanation? This is easily reproducible. If it is a "dumb" question, please explain why.

Comment: Raymond's blog suggests it should NOT be listed as a DLL if it's only been opened as a data file. Btw the downvotes were not mine.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - file not kept open in all case. here all task in how file is mapped - as image or as data. and requested write access to file or not. error exactly at this point - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/executable-images

Comment: A handle references a File object that references the File/Stream Control Block for the file. For mapping a file as image/data, the Memory Manager uses the FCB's [section object pointers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563687). When opening a file for write access or setting the delete disposition of a file, the filesystem calls [`MmFlushImageSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549808) with either `MmFlushForWrite` or `MmFlushForDelete`. A File object opened for a hard link uses the section object pointers from the underlying SCB/FCB.

Comment: Interestingly, in Windows 10 I have no problem deleting a file mapped as read-only data, such as this `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` example. I checked `!ca` on the data control area in the debugger, and it appears to be using a special kind of delete-on-close flag. Unlike setting the delete disposition on an open file, it's actually unlinked in this case. The file doesn't show up in a directory listing.

Comment: Ah, I was using cmd.exe to delete the file and didn't know it has a new `cmd!FastDeleteFile` function for deleting files by opening them via `NtOpenFile` with `FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`. Apparently we can open a file mapped as read-only data with the delete-on-close, and it won't fail with `STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE`. But calling `NtSetInformationFile` to set the delete disposition does fail, which is why a direct `DeleteFile` failed when I tried it later.

Comment: @eryksun - direct `ZwDeleteFile` fail in this case ? (can not check now yourself)

Comment: @RbMm, yes, `NtDeleteFile` also works. It's a quicker way of doing a `FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` without actually creating a real File object. The only case that fails is the normal `DeleteFile` way of `NtOpenFile` with `DELETE` access following by `NtSetInformationFile` to set the delete disposition. I'm going to check the FastFat driver to see if opening when flagged delete-on-close checks `MmFlushForDelete` or just does `MmFlushForWrite`, which could explain the difference.

Comment: @RbMm, my suspicion [is confirmed](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/aa6e0b36eb932099fa4eb950a6f5e289a23b6d6e/filesys/fastfat/create.c#L3572). Assuming NTFS works like the reference fastfat driver, it doesn't check `MmFlushForDelete` when a file is opened delete-on-close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your case can be more clear shown in next test

```
ULONG TestImageAccess(PCWSTR name, BOOL bImage, BOOL bRequestWriteAccess)
{
    SetLastError(0);

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(name, GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        HANDLE hSection = CreateFileMappingW(hFile, 0, 
            bImage ? PAGE_READONLY|SEC_IMAGE : PAGE_READONLY|SEC_COMMIT, 0, 0, 0);

        CloseHandle(hFile);

        if (hSection)
        {
            hFile = CreateFileW(name, 
                bRequestWriteAccess ? GENERIC_WRITE : GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

            CloseHandle(hSection);

            if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                CloseHandle(hFile);
            }
        }
    }

    return GetLastError();
}

void TestImageAccess(PCWSTR filename)
{
    TestImageAccess(filename, TRUE, TRUE);  // ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION
    TestImageAccess(filename, FALSE, TRUE); // NOERROR
    TestImageAccess(filename, TRUE, FALSE); // NOERROR
    TestImageAccess(filename, FALSE, FALSE);// NOERROR
}
```

we got `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` when we request **write access** to file and file mapped **as image**

this case is described in [`Executable Images`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/executable-images):

> If the user wants write access to the file, make sure there is not a
>   process mapping this file as an image

the call to `MmFlushImageSection` with `MmFlushForWrite` fail and you got `STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION` - exactly at this line.

`LoadLibraryEx` with flag `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` create section on file with `SEC_COMMIT` when with 0 in flag - with `SEC_IMAGE` - so as image section

the privileges here absolute not related

> How would one determine if you truly have exclusive access to a file
>   when libraries are loaded?

simply open file with access which you need and do what you need. and yes, you can got error `ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE` when you try truncate mapped file. but here nothing can be done. example 2

```
ULONG TestImage2(PCWSTR name)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(name, GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        HANDLE hSection = CreateFileMappingW(hFile, 0, PAGE_READONLY|SEC_COMMIT, 0, 0, 0);

        CloseHandle(hFile);

        if (hSection)
        {
            PVOID pv = MapViewOfFile(hSection, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);

            CloseHandle(hSection);

            if (pv)
            {
                hFile = CreateFileW(name,GENERIC_WRITE|GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

                if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                {
                    FILE_END_OF_FILE_INFO eof = {  };
                    // ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE will be here
                    SetFileInformationByHandle(hFile, FileEndOfFileInfo, &eof, sizeof(eof));
                    CloseHandle(hFile);
                }

                UnmapViewOfFile(pv);
            }
        }
    }

    return GetLastError();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. As a workaround I've decided I can attempt to set the end of file marker (same size) via SetFileInformationByHandle and check for error 1224 (ERROR_USER_MAPPED_FILE) as a means to to detect this. Is there a better way to determine if a process has a mapped file section?

Comment: @ConfusedDeveloper - for what you need detect this ? what is you target goal ?  and even you somehow detect this, after it at any time situation can changed. so what is sense in this kind of detect ? you real target is what ?

Comment: and set end of file to less size than section - this is not check, but file data damage

Comment: I was going to set the size to the existing size, no change to file size. Unfortunately this isn't going to work, cause it turns out you can set the same size without error. As for use case, think detecting files in use in the event you need to overwrite them. In this case they can be scheduled for replacement on reboot via MoveFileEx.